# How do you copy/duplicate a form in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

How do you copy/duplicate a form in Cognito Forms?

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Yes, you can copy/duplicate one of your current Cognito Forms by clicking the "+ New form" button at the top of your forms page. You can then select the bottom option "Copy an existing form". You will then be prompted to select the form you would like to copy from your current form list. Once selected you will be taken to the build page with your copied form.